# XSL transform template match

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a following XML document with the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <div class="WordSection1">
        <p class="ChapterNumber"> </p>
        <h1 class="ChapterTitle" id="sigil_toc_id_6">Other Sources Referred To</h1>
        <p class="ChapterSub-Title"> </p>
        <RefMaterial type="other">
            <RefTitle>Agreement on Trade-Related Aspects of <searchHighlight xmlns="">Intellectual</searchHighlight> Property Rights (“TRIPS Agreement”). See Marrakesh Agreement Establishing the World Trade Organization, Annex 1C</RefTitle>
        </RefMaterial>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now I am trying to convert this XML to HTML using the following XSL stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
    <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:param name="portlet"/>
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="*:body[descendant::*:RefMaterial]">
        <div class="lib-ref">
            <div class="lib-references">
                <xsl:for-each select="descendant::node()">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="name()='RefMaterial' and not(string-length(@type)=0)">
                            <div class="other-reference lib-reference">
                                <div class="other-reference-title">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="*:RefTitle except *:ref"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </div>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="searchHighlight">
        <span class="search-highlight" id="search-highlight-{format-number(count(preceding::searchHighlight)+1,'0000')}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and this is the current HTML obtained:

```
<div class="lib-ref">
    <div class="lib-references">
        <div class="other-reference lib-reference">
            <div class="other-reference-title">Agreement on Trade-Related Aspects of Intellectual Property Rights (“TRIPS Agreement”). See Marrakesh Agreement Establishing the World Trade Organization, Annex 1C</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How should I alter the XSL to obtain the following HTML line. Basically to put the search-highlight class on to the word.

```
<div class="other-reference-title">Agreement on Trade-Related Aspects of <span class="search-highlight" id="search-highlight-0001">Intellectual</span> Property Rights (“TRIPS Agreement”). See Marrakesh Agreement Establishing the World Trade Organization, Annex 1C</div>
```

Many thanks for reading up this post!

Comment: You seem to have written or used or copied a template that handles the transformation of that particular input but you don't use `<xsl:apply-templates/>` further up in the processing chain, instead you try to output a text node with `xsl:value-of`. So write templates matching the nodes you want to transform and use `<xsl:apply-templates/>` (perhaps with a `select` attribute) to process child nodes or descendants. And drop the `for-each` over descendants.

Comment: See how to use apply-templates, I.e. here https://www.educba.com/xslt-apply-templates/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```xml
<xsl:value-of select="*:RefTitle except *:ref"/>
```

which outputs the text including all subnodes, regardless of what these subnodes are, use

```xml
<xsl:apply-templates select="*:RefTitle except *:ref"/>
```

which applies to every node individually: text directly contained in `RefTitle` is output, but subnodes like `searchHighlight` are treated according to their own template, so that your `<xsl:template match="searchHighlight">` comes into play.